# dismissing candidate causes circle of death never to end

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

We have a job listing, I applied for it to test it.  I dismissed the candidate by checking the checkbox and clicking the button to "Dismiss Candidate".  The webpage does not error out however you get the spinning circle endlessly.

[image]

Comment: I had to manually kill this process it went on for over 5 minutes.

Comment: (In the spirit of Bill and Ted), "Dude, you dismissed yourself!" :)

Comment: Oh, dear.  Is this what happens to candidates in your company?!  ;-)

Comment: @MikeRobinson - No I think this is just to get them off your list of possible good candidates.  jobs developers this is really sorry to put it poorly done.  You dismiss the candidate but the candidate has no clue he / she is dismissed.  This is related to my "left in limbo" meta post.  Why is there so many weird and horribly done pitfalls in careers / jobs? Even the icon sets / color schemes on jobs are not done correctly.  To me jobs was written for fun and suddenly someone liked the idea and we are in band aid mode where everything is fixed with a bandaid.  This sucks..it really does.

Comment: Thanks for the report; we haven't seen or heard of this problem occurring for other users, but we'll look into it. Were there any errors in the console when this happened?

Comment: No console errors I can try again tomorrow.

Comment: Any particular reason you haven't obscured candidate name in the screenshot?

Comment: Phil it's just me I could care less.

Comment: @JonH I did some digging through our traffic and error logs and I don't see anything unusual with those requests. I see a dismiss request, then a couple hours later an undismiss and a dismiss. All went through fine and the server response times were normal. Did you do more than that (and maybe it never reached the server)?

Comment: Steve this only happened on the first dismiss.  Hours later I tried again to undismiss which is a strange word, shouldn't you use retain instead of undismiss?  In any event it didn't happen again...I don't know what to tell you...it happened to me the first time.  Could be some issue with our internal iPrism or firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again for reporting this. We weren't able to reproduce the error after several attempts, so I'm going to close this. I suspect it was just a network hiccup, but if it happens again please let us know!